# MySQL controls with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, datasource

I am working with mysql as db server.
What controls can i use to show a table and modify it's contents.
I have read somewhere that sqlDataSource can be used only with SQL Server. Are there any costum controls for mysql Server to manipulate the data?

If i have misunderstood something or if i made some incorrect statements please correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MySQL Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/dotnet.html). The MySQL Connector is a fully managed ADO.NET component which provides specific implementation for all ADO.NET classes.